# Oracle Materialized View Refresh Group - Montly Interval

Tags: oracle

I have a few Materialized Views that I need to update weekly and monthly.

So for the weekly I'm using:

```
execute DBMS_REFRESH.MAKE(
name=>'LPMVRefresh_Weekly_1',
list=>'mySchema.MV1_mv,mySchema.MV2_mv',
next_date => TO_DATE('2013-09-08:00:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS'),
interval =>'sysdate+7');
```

How can I do so they refresh monthly, say every 1st of the month at 1 am? Is there something like Interval => sysdate+monthly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next month's 1st day 1am can be calculated using the following SQL:

```
SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1), 'MONTH')+1/24 AS ANSWER FROM DUAL;
```

The most probably it can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks! Base on your comment, I went with interval =>'ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1)'